# unexpexted output in c++ 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, 2d

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2qf4.png)

[i/o formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZZHV.png)

[sample test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNph2.png)

For a given two-dimensional integer array/list of size (N x M), print the array/list in a sine wave order, i.e, print the first column top to bottom, next column bottom to top and so on.

I am unable to get the expected output for this problem. Please find my code below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void wavePrint(int input[][2], int nRows, int mCols)
{
    //Write your code here
    for(int i=0;i<mCols;i++){
        int j=0;
        for(;j<nRows;j++){
            cout<<input[j][i]<<" ";
        }
        i++;
        for(;j>=0;j--){
            cout<<input[j][i]<<" ";
        }
    }
}




int main()
{
    
        int input[][2]={{5,6},{2,4}};
        wavePrint(input, 2, 2);
        cout << endl;
    
}
```

Comment: Yes, the shown algorithm is completely wrong. Hint: write out, on paper, a very small matrix, 4x4. The matrix originally contains numbers 1 through 16 in consecutive order. Now, write out what the resulting algorithm specifies the output should be, in a 2nd matrix. Now compute, from the output, the coordinates of each cell in the 2nd matrix that comes from the first matrix. Write those coordinates in a third matrix. Now stare at the third matrix, and see what the real pattern is, and then the problem with the shown code becomes obvious.

Comment: Along with algorithm, you forgot to decrement `j` in your current program, resulting in printing garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have enough reputation to comment, the only thing I can do is answer.

Your primary issue is that you are incrementing the `i` loop index inside the loop. You don't need to/want to do this.

Walk through your code and track the variable values on each line (or use a debugger to do this) and you will see what the output looks like and where you've gone wrong.